# How to write custom error messages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My account model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_exclusion_of :subdomain, :in => %w(www),
    :message => "Subdomain {{value}} is reserved"

    validates_inclusion_of :size, :in => %w(small medium large),
    :message =>"{{value}} is not a valid size" 

    validates_presence_of :size
    :message => "size not selected"

end
```

Here I want to write an error message that displays "**size not selected**" if the size is blank or "**{{value}} is not a valid size**"

The issue is that I want to display either of the messages and not both.

Answer (score 1):

Add `allow_blank: true` here

```
validates_inclusion_of :size, :in => %w(small medium large),
:message =>"{{value}} is not a valid size", allow_blank: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, the accepted way to set custom error messages is to use locales.

OR

```
 class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do |user|
    user.errors.add_to_base("Country can't be blank") if user.country_iso.blank?
  end
```

use your fields in place of country